# Insert array_intersect_key array data into a database table

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to programming, I have created a form with several check boxes and text fields. Each text field will activated if the check box is selected. The intersect key array is used to get all the checked check-box names and text field values. I want to insert these array data into a database table.

Can anyone give me some codes to do this. Thanks :)

This is function.php file

```
    global $usedTexts;
    $usedTexts = array();

    function postdata(){
        if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && array_key_exists("t", $_POST)  && is_array($_POST["t"]) && array_key_exists("cb", $_POST) && is_array($_POST["cb"])) {
             $usedTexts = array_intersect_key($_POST["t"], $_POST["cb"]);
        }
    }
```

and this is index.php file

```
  <?php include_once("function.php"); ?>
  <?php postdata(); ?>

  <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb[1]" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('t1').disabled=!this.checked;" />
      <input type="number" max="5" min="1" id="t1" name="t[1]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><br />

      <input type="checkbox" name="cb[2]" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('t2').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
      <input type="number" max="5" min="1"id="t2" name="t[2]" value="" disabled="disabled" /><br /><br />

      <input type="checkbox" name="cb[3]" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('t3').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
      <input type="number" max="5" min="1"id="t3" name="t[3]" value="" disabled="disabled" /><br /><br />

      <input type="checkbox" name="cb[4]" value="" onclick="document.getElementById('t4').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
      <input type="number" max="5" min="1"id="t4" name="t[4]" value="" disabled="disabled" /><br /><br />

      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: table name is mysubjects and columns are subjectId (primary key) and subjectExp. checkbox values should insert into subjectId and text field values should go to subjectExp. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
      if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && array_key_exists("t", $_POST)  && is_array($_POST["t"]) && array_key_exists("cb", $_POST) && is_array($_POST["cb"])) {
        $usedTexts = array_intersect_key($_POST["t"], $_POST["cb"]);

                foreach($usedTexts as $subjectId=>$subjectExp){

                    $query=  "insert into mysubjects (subjectId, subjectExp) values('".$subjectId."','".$subjectExp."')";
                    //execute your query, before that make sure you have established the database connection
                }               

      }
```

Comment: i want to insert data into subjectId column also from the array

Comment: subjectId added from array, please check

Comment: NP. Glad to help you.